# How to expose only properties that needed with Web API?

Tags: rest, web-applications, asp.net-web-api, poco

I'm new to ASP.NET Web API.

I saw examples of how you can get and return POCOs in RESTful web application.

I wonder how in real world application you can pass only some of the properties of your POCO (for security and/or message size reasons).

I found that I can use the '[ScriptIgnore]' attribute, but I'm looking for a way to customize which properties to pass according to the requesting controller, for example.

Does there is a nice, out of the box way, to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest is to decorate your POCO with `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute` and the members you want to include with `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute` i.e.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyType
{
  [DataMember]
  public string Property1 {get; set;}
  public string Property2 {get; set;}
  public string Property3 {get; set;}
}
```

In this case only `Property1` will be serialized. It;s worth noting, that both `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` and `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` will respect `DataContract` so you don't need any XML/JSON specific attrbiutes.

Now, this will work in simpler solutions, for a real, well rounded approach you'd probably need to resort to DTOs instead of exposing your Models to the client.

You could use `Automapper` for that, and project Models to DTOs - you have a good introductory article here http://www.mono-software.com/blog/post/Mono/120/Using-AutoMapper-to-handle-DTOs/. Also, with Automapper you can have different types of DTOs created from the same base Model, which, I understand, is something you are interested in.

Comment: I agree with Filip's second half. Completely decouple your domain from your resources and use automapper.

Comment: The second half indeed looks as a good solution for my problem. Thank you Filip!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return multiple manifestations of the same model from different controller it is a harmful design (according to me). If you still want to do it you can make the unwanted properties to 'null' and return the model.

To handle the null objects to ignore from serializing you have to do this somewhere while configuring your formatters (right in global.asax):

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```